# loop through divs for nested divs with href inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cheerio

```
<div class="view-content">
    <div class="views-row views-row-1">   
        <div class="views-field">
            <span class="field-content">
                <a href="link1">Name for link1
                    <img src="image1">
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="views-field-title">
            <span class="field-content">
                <a href="link1">
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="views-row views-row-2">
        <div class="views-field">
          <span class="field-content">
              <a href="link2">Name for Link2
                  <img src="image2">
              </a>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="views-field-title">
            <span class="field-content">
                <a href="link2">
                </a>
            </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am using node with request, and cheerio to request the data and scrape accordingly.

I am seeking the href from link1 and link2, I got it to work for one link, but it does not scale out when I try to loop it.

```
  const data ={
       link:"div.views-field > span > a" 
   },
   pageData = {};
   Object.keys(data).forEach(k => {
       pageData[k] = $(data[k]).attr("href");});

     console.log(pageData);
```

Comment: If jQuery syntax is available, then why not `$("div.views-field > span > a").each(function() { pageData.push(this.href) }); ` or something like `var pageData = $("div.views-field > span > a").map(function(_,link) { return llink.attr('href') });`

Comment: Have you tried jsdom for scraping? This way you can just use normal document.querySelector calls, which makes this way easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with `$(data[k]).attr("href");` is the right idea, but there's no loop here. There should be 2 elements matching this selector but your code only grabs the first.

Changing this to a `[...$(data[k])].map(e => $(e).attr("href"))` lets you get `href` attributes from all matching elements.

I'm not crazy about `pageData` being global and using a `forEach` when a `map` seems more appropriate, so here's my suggestion:

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const data = {
  link: "div.views-field > span > a",
};
const pageData = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data).map(([k, v]) =>
    [k, [...$(v)].map(e => $(e).attr("href"))]
  )
);
console.log(pageData);
```